# Why can't an enum extend a class in Java?

Tags: java, enums, subclass, extends

Why can't have enum extending some class in Java?

Examples below shows, that:

1. we can have normal enum `E1`.
2. we can have "complex" enum `E2`.
3. but we can't obtain the same complex enum, by combining some class and extending it with enum.

For example:

```
public class Try_ExtendEnum {

    public static enum E1 {
        North,
        East,
        South,
        West
    }

    public static enum E2 {

        North(0),
        Eash(90),
        South(180),
        West(270);

        private double degrees;

        E2(double degrees) {
            this.degrees = degrees;
        }

        public double getDegrees() {
            return degrees;
        }
    }

    public static class DegreesMeasure {

        private double degrees;

        public DegreesMeasure(double degrees) {
            this.degrees = degrees;
        }

        public double getDegrees() {
            return degrees;
        }
    }

    public static enum E3 extends DegreesMeasure {
        North(0),
        Eash(90),
        South(180),
        West(270);

        E3(double degrees) {
            super(degrees);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DegreesMeasure dm = new DegreesMeasure(123);
        E3 e = dm; // should not be possible, since E3 is a subclass and not obliged to hold superclass

        DegreesMeasure dm2 = E3.Nort; // just holding "tagged" version of instance; see no any problem 

    }


}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

An `enum` cannot `extends` another class because an `enum` already `extends Enum<T>`. That class provides all the `enum` functionality.

An `enum` can, however, `implements` an `interface`:

```
public interface DegreesMeasure {
    double getDegrees();
}

public enum E3 implements DegreesMeasure {
    NORTH(0),
    EAST(90),
    SOUTH(180),
    WEST(270);

    private final double degrees;

    E3(double degrees) {
        this.degress = degrees;
    }

    @Override
    public double getDegrees() {
        return degrees;
    }
}
```

And this would seem to make a lot more sense in your case anyway.

Also, traditionally, as an `enum` value is in essence a `public static final` value it is named in the same way - in block caps with underscores.

**EDIT**

From comments - how to override methods in individual `enum` values. This is often used in a Factory Pattern. Assume we have a `Widget` and a `WidgetFactory`. We have two different widget types, small and large. These are represented by the classes `SmallWidget` and `LargeWidget`.

```
interface Widget {}

interface WidgetFactory {
    Widget get();
}

class LargeWidget implements Widget {}

class SmallWidget implements Widget {}
```

Now we can implement the `WidgetFactory` as an `enum` thus:

```
enum WidgetFactoryImpl implements WidgetFactory {
    SMALL {
        @Override
        public Widget get() {
            return new SmallWidget();
        }
    },
    LARGE {
        @Override
        public Widget get() {
            return new LargeWidget();
        }
    };

}
```

In general having polymorphic behaviour on `enum` can be extremely powerful.

Comment: Also, quite interestingly, you can override the methods separately for each enum value if required.

Comment: @user2610529 added an example of that.

Comment: oh wow, I didn't realise enums could implement interfaces! I knew they could have abstract methods themselves though, which I always found cool. So thanks for revealing this tidbit to me!

Comment: Really I'm seeing the argument that enum can't extends another class or enum because they already extends Enum<T>. This is the Stupid argument I ever seen in Java. What you think about other classes ? why they can extends other classes even they already extends Object class?

Comment: @UnKnown `Object` is special - everything `extends Object` as the **single parent `class`**. So `Parent -> Object`, if we add a child then `Child -> Parent -> Object`. `extends Object` is added to any `class` _that does not `extends` another `class`_ by the compiler. Java does **not** support multiple inheritance.

Comment: @BoristheSpider excellent point about `extends Object` is added to any `class` that does not `extends` another `class` by the compiler. So `extends Enum<T>` will be added to enum by the compiler, right?

Answer (score 3):

According to [the Java Language Specification, Chapter 8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9), each enum is implicitly final and is a subclass of Enum. So an enum already inherits from another class, making it a subclass of another class would break Java's single inheritance paradigm. An enum can, however, implement an interface.

Comment: @BoristheSpider perhaps your answer wasn't visible to user2610529 at the time of answering

Comment: I indeed didn't see your answer until I posted mine.